# Swift -- Sprite Kit -- Scenes have different sizes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am programming a game but I have one problem. I have two scenes. (1. GameScene 2. PlayScene). The GameScene displays the PlayButton. If you press the PlayButton the PlayScene will be displayed. The PlayScene displays the game. If you lose the Game, the GameScene will be presented again.

GameScene --> PlayScene --> GameScene

This is the code, which is in the GameScene and presents the PlayScene.

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {                  // Wenn position des klicks gleich mit position des play button
            println("Go to the game")
            var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = self.view! as SKView
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

This is the code, which is in the PlayScene and presents the GameScene again.

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
                let skView = self.view as SKView!
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
```

My Problem is that the GameScene has first a different size than the GameScene which is presented after the PlayScene. I can't show photos because I don't have 10 reputations -.-, but I can explain it. For example: The PlayButton in the GameScene, which is presented after the program starts, is smaller than the PlayButton, which is presented in the GameScene after the PlayScene is presented. 
I tried to change the scaleModes but that didn't work.

Here are the links for the photos, which show my problem.

This is the "second" GameScene presented:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B57TI4Xur5Fldy1EcVh6NmVIdm8&authuser=0

This is the "first" GameScene presented:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B57TI4Xur5FlR3ZXT2NFSEZRZHc&authuser=0

Comment: You  cannot upload pics, but you can post links.

Comment: In the sks file for your GameScene, change. The size of the scene, the default is too big.

Comment: I don´t think that this is the problem. If you open both pictures you will see that the first GameScene presented has a perfect size. But the GameScene (I know that there is only one GameScene) presented after the PlayScene has a different size. That is the reason why there is no problem with the scene size. In my opinion there is a problem with the scale or i have to add another method. I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that you aren't using the same settings as you are for the first scene. Try this.

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.size = self.size
            scene.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but it didn´t worked. I tried some other changes and it worked but I don´t know why.

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
                let skView = self.view as SKView!
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
```

Now both Scenes have the same size.